# How to create a public form for other sites in php?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, page-curl

Hi I need a public order form to provide registered users in my site. I can give a link to the users then user can copy paste that link to their own sites. If any person order via from the user site. the details must be saved in my site. How can create that kind of a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Provide the user sites with the HTML form the form, and let the form submit to your site. Your site would store the information and then redirect to the user site.
- Similarly, let the user sites include the form using an iframe or some javascript.
- Let the form submit to the users site, and let them inform you of the order by submitting some data to your site. This can be done using Curl, or SOAP, or such.

Comment: I need a secure method. can you tell me which one is the most secure method?

Comment: Use HTTPS for both the form and the forms target.